# Can PowerShell synch Nuget packages between Devs' workstations?

Tags: powershell, nuget

Seeking PS script that would

1. inspect packages installed on my
   MasterWorkstation, then;
2. Produce a list of commands that can
   be executed on other workstations so
   as to produce a synched dev image.

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NuGet doesn't really have the concept of packages that are installed at the machine level. Instead, packages are installed in each project that needs it.

When packages are installed in a project, a repository.config file is created that lists what's installed. Using that file, you can then easily re-fetch the same packages on another machine, keeping things essentially in sync.

See my [post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html) for more details on this workflow.